# Get categories which do not have any product from a particular category

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to write a sql query to get the categories which does not have any of the products from particular category. Let say I have a,b,c,d,e categories and each category have some products. Now I need to get all the categories which done not include products of category a.

Categories table:

```
id  name
1   A
2   B
3   C
4   D
5   E
```

category_products table:

```
product_id   category_id
1            1
1            2
2            3
2            1
4            3
3            2
3            4
3            5
4            5
```

Query I used is below which gives B,C,D,E (not as expected)

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.name FROM category_products AS p
LEFT JOIN categories AS c ON c.id = p.category_id
WHERE p.product_id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT product_id FROM category_products where category_id = 1)
ORDER BY c.name
```

But I need results to be categories D,E which don't have any products from category A.

Comment: What you're asking is not clear. What result are you expecting?

Comment: @AlvinThompson Expected result is categories D and E, which dont have any of the products from category A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do one more inner query, e.g.:

```
SELECT name
FROM categories 
where id NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT category_id 
    FROM category_products WHERE 
    product_id IN (
        SELECT product_id FROM category_products WHERE category_id = 1
    )
);
```

This would return D and E.

Here's the **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/78313/1/0)**.

Answer (score 0):

You should use inner join

```
  select distinct  t2.name
  from category_products t1 
  inner join Categories t2 on t2.id = t1.category_id
  where t1.product_id not in 
   (select p.product_id
   from category_products p
   inner join Categories c on c.id = p.category_id
   where c.name ='A')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it gives result as  B,C,D,E.

Answer (score 0):

I would be inclined to do this using `group by` and `having`:

```
select pc.product_id
from category_products pc join
     categories c
     on c.id = pc.category_id
group by pc.product_id
having sum(c.name = 'A') = 0;
```